# TextView смещаются в низ

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

TextView сместилась в низ как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1.1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/button_table"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_picture"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_picture" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/button_table"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cartridge_case"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_table"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bullet"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1.4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/button_table"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_skull"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/button_table"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bullet_pen"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/button_table"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_arrow"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow"
                android:duplicateParentState="false"/>
        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text="@string/a_1.1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text="@string/a_1.2"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text="@string/a_2.1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_table"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался надо было `layout_height` поменять на `match_parent`. Я так долго искал ответ, а оказалась всё так просто.